# logback.xml Date only

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am new to coding and stackoverflow, We are using logback for logging our application, as of now we are using {fileName}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log naming convention for the time based rolling policy (rolling take place each and every day) and have set 30 days as the maximum time for a log to be stored in the application. We need to change the naming convention to only date format ({fileName}.%d{dd}.log). But we are getting "The date format in fileNamePattern will result in collisions in the names of archived log files." error

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="dailyRollingFileAppender"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/deliveryService.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>logs/deliveryService.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <!-- Delete log after 30 days -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>


<!-- Send logs to both console and file audit -->
<logger name="com.bnsf" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Comment: What have you tried and researched so far?

Comment: Tried giving logs/deliveryService.%d{dd}.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in a month like February, with only 28/29 days, in a 30-day windows you will have deliveryService.01.log and deliveryService.02.log files twice.

Comment: Because the name of the file is constructed with the name of the day-in-a-month, (deliveryService.%d{dd}.log), if you have a 30 day log retention, on February 1st your file is deliveryService.01.log, on February 2nd is deliveryService.02.log and so on. After 28 days, on February 28 you get deliveryService.28.log, but the next day is March 1st, and you'll get deliveryService.01.log again, but since only 29 days have passed since the start of the window, you can't delete the already existing deliveryService.01.log, therefore you got a collision.

Comment: So a possible solution is to use 
<maxHistory>28</maxHistory>
unless you really need to keep your last 30 days of logging.